# FreeRTOS questions on LED control

Tags: c, embedded, esp32, freertos, esp-idf

I'm trying to make an HTTP controlled LED. One end is a website (not made by me, but by the people that proposed this challenge) and the other end is just a button.

The website contains a toggle switch that controls the LED status:

[image]

And the tactile switch has no state retention.

I created a task with freeRTOS to constantly check the value of the LED variable and turn it on or off accordingly, but I feel thisn isn't the proper way to do this, since it's always setting the gpio pin to high, not just when it switches.

```
void LEDControl (void *parameter) {
    // ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Led status %d", LED);
    while (1)
    {
        if (LED)
        {
            gpio_set_level(LEDPIN, 1);
        } else if (!LED) {
            gpio_set_level(LEDPIN, 0);
        }
    }
    
}
```

What would be the best solution to this? An event handler?

I have no experience using event handlers or interrupts, so this is new for me.

Also, for my button status: should I have a task that monitors when the button is pressed? I think that this is not a proper implementation, also. Should I go for interrupts?

I'm constantly having watchdog triggers. I'm assuming my task is taking way too long and something is not working properly.

```
void buttonAction (void *parameter) {
    // setup
    char output_buffer[MAX_HTTP_OUTPUT_BUFFER] = {0};
    int content_length = 0;
    esp_http_client_config_t config = {
        .url = "link-to-web-api",
        .method = HTTP_METHOD_POST,
    };
    esp_http_client_handle_t client = esp_http_client_init(&config);
    esp_http_client_set_header(client, "Content-Type", "application/json");
    char *post_data;
    esp_err_t err;
    while (1)
    {
        if (gpio_get_level(Button) == 0) {
            if(xSemaphoreTake(LED_Mutex, 0)) {
                LED = !LED;
                // POST REQUEST,
                post_data = (char *) pvPortMalloc(15 * sizeof(char));
                if (LED == false)
                {
                    memcpy(post_data, "{\"value\":\"0\"}", 14);
                    ESP_LOGI("Post Data:", "%s", post_data);
                } else {
                    memcpy(post_data, "{\"value\":\"1\"}", 14);
                    ESP_LOGI("Post Data:", "%s", post_data);
                }
                err = esp_http_client_open(client, strlen(post_data));
                if (err == ESP_OK) {
                    esp_http_client_write(client, post_data, strlen(post_data));
                    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "%s", post_data);
                    vPortFree(post_data);
                    content_length = esp_http_client_fetch_headers(client);
                    if (content_length >= 0) {
                        esp_http_client_read_response(client, output_buffer, MAX_HTTP_OUTPUT_BUFFER);
                    }
                }
                esp_http_client_cleanup(client);
                xSemaphoreGive(LED_Mutex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What task kicks the watchdog?  What are the relative priorities of the tasks?  The LEDControl() task never blocks so a lower priority task will never run.  Why is LEDControl() even a task?  What is the purpose of LED_Mutex?  What is the harm in "always setting the GPIO pin"?  It seems like you have much more concerning issues than that.

Answer (score 2):

> it's always setting the gpio pin to high, not just when it switches.

Since setting a GPIO output takes no significant time, repeatedly asserting an output to the same state is not generally a problem.

> I'm constantly having watchdog triggers. I'm assuming my task is taking way too long

That is not the problem; rather your LED task loop never yields so will only be preempted by interrupts and higher priority tasks (or same priority tasks if you have round-robing scheduling enabled).  Well behaved tasks in an RTOS environment must block on some event be that *time passed* (a delay), a task event flag, a semaphore, message arrival or some other IPC or task-synchronisation mechanism.

In this case a simple delay would prevent `LEDControl()` from hogging the CPU:

```
void LEDControl( void* ) 
{
    for(;;)
    {
        // Update LED 10 times per second
        gpio_set_level( LEDPIN, LED ? 1 : 0 ) ;
        vTaskDelay( 100 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS ) ;
    } 
}
```

Note also that your `buttonAction()` task has the same problem and does not yield the CPU while polling for button presses, and should have:

```
for(;;)
{
    if (gpio_get_level(Button) == 0) 
    {
         ...
    }

    // Poll 10 times/second
    vTaskDelay( 100 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS ) ;
}
```

If you only want to update the LED on change of button state, you could do:

```
void LEDControl( void* ) 
{
    bool previous_LED = LED ;
    gpio_set_level( LEDPIN, LED ? 1 : 0 ) ;

    for(;;)
    {
        // On change of state...
        if( LED != previous_LED )
        {
            // Update LED state
            gpio_set_level( LEDPIN, LED ? 1 : 0 ) ;
            previous_LED = LED ;
        }
        vTaskDelay( 100 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS ) ;
    } 
}
```

However there is no real benefit in terms of performance, and a distinct disbenefit in terms of complexity.  The general technique however may have merit in other circumstances - where you need to perform processing once-only on change of state.

That said a better method (and more generally applicable to other scenarios) is not to poll a shared memory variable (`LED` in this case), but to use the RTOS support for task signalling and synchronisation.  In this case `buttonAction()` might simply set a binary semaphore on change-of state, such that `LEDControl()` would become:

```
static volatile int LED_state = 0 ;
    
void LEDControl( void* ) 
{
    for(;;)
    {
        // wait for toggle semaphore
        xSempahoreTake( sem_led_toggle, portMAX_DELAY ) ;

        // Set LED state
        gpio_set_level( LEDPIN, LED_state ) ;
    } 
}
```

That way `LEDControl()` is only active when a change of state is required - minimising CPU usage.  In this example, that is perhaps not critical, but in non-trivial applications with many tasks and scheduling events, the general pattern can be used to ensure optimum CPU utilisation.

Then in `buttonAction()` in place of:

```
LED = !LED ;
```

you would have:

```
LED_state = !LED_state ;
xSemaphoreGive( sem_led_toggle ) ;
```

With respect to the `buttonAction()` task, it is not clear what the mutex is for in `buttonAction()`.  Mutexes are for protecting resources, but its name suggests that resource is the LED, or possibly simply the variable `LED`.  Neither seems to be necessary and the mutex is in any case held for much longer that the access to LED.  Moreover a mutex serves no purpose is only one task ever takes it - the resource is already mutually exclusive by virtue of being accessed in only one task.  If the mutex is in fact protecting some other resource, such as the HTTP stack, then a less misleading name should be used, but in that case I would hope that the HTTP API was already thread safe.

Also the large and permanently allocated `output_buffer` is wasteful and unnecessary since you do not actually use that data.  Use `esp_http_client_flush_response` to discard unwanted response data.  A further issue is the clear resource leak where `post_data` is allocated unconditionally, but only deallocated when `esp_http_client_open` is not in error.  It is a short and fixed length buffer and need not be dynamically allocated at all.

I would suggest something like:

```
void buttonAction( void* ) 
{
    // setup
    esp_http_client_config_t config = {
        .url = "link-to-web-api",
        .method = HTTP_METHOD_POST,
    };
    esp_http_client_handle_t client = esp_http_client_init(&config);
    esp_http_client_set_header(client, "Content-Type", "application/json");
    
    for(;;)
    {
        if (gpio_get_level(Button) == 0) 
        {
            // Toggle LED
            LED_state = !LED_state ;
            cSemaphoreGive( sem_led_dem ) 

            char post_data[15] = {0} ;
            sprintf( post_data, 
                     "{\"value\":\"%c\"}", 
                     LED_State ? '1' : '0' ) ;
            ESP_LOGI("Post Data:", "%s", post_data);
                    
            esp_err_t err = esp_http_client_open(client, strlen(post_data));
            if( err == ESP_OK ) 
            {
                esp_http_client_write(client, post_data, strlen(post_data));
                ESP_LOGI(TAG, "%s", post_data);
                
                int content_length = esp_http_client_fetch_headers(client);
                if( content_length >= 0 ) 
                {
                    int discard_count = 0 ;
                    esp_http_client_flush_response( client, *discard_count ) ;
                }
            }
            
            esp_http_client_cleanup(client);
        }
        
        // Button polling 10 per second
        vTaskDelay( 100 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS ) ;
    }
}
```

All that said, and with respect to:

> Also, for my button status: should I have a task that monitors when the button is pressed? I think that this is not a proper implementation, also. Should I go for interrupts?

The task `LEDControl()` serves no real purpose here other than to demonstrate two communicating sequential processes.  Even if that is the sole purpose of this exercise it would make more sense from a design point of view to have one task that polls the button and toggles the LED, and gives a *binary* semaphore to *separate* task that deals with the HTTP interaction.  That would be a far more cohesive design and make more sense in a terms of real-time processing since the button polling and LED toggling are short and deterministic whereas you have no control over the timing and performance of the network interaction, which would in your implementation interfere with the timing of your button polling and responsiveness of the LED setting.

So in that case:

```
static volatile int LED_state = 0 ;

void buttonAction( void* ) 
{
    bool button_down = gpio_get_level(Button) == 0 ;
    gpio_set_level( LEDPIN, LED_state ? 1 : 0 ) ;

    for(;;)
    {
        // On button-down event...
        if( !button_down && gpio_get_level(Button) == 0 ) 
        {
            button_down = true ;

            // Toggle and set LED state
            LEDstate = !LED_state
            gpio_set_level( LEDPIN, LED_state ) ;
            
            // Trigger HTTP
            xSemaphoreGive( http_trigger_sem ) ;
        }
        // On button release...
        else if( gpio_get_level(Button) != 0 )
        {
            button_down = false ;
        }
        
        // Button polling 10 per second
        vTaskDelay( 100 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS ) ;         
    } 
}
```

```
void httpTask( void* ) 
{
    // setup
    esp_http_client_config_t config = {
        .url = "link-to-web-api",
        .method = HTTP_METHOD_POST,
    };
    esp_http_client_handle_t client = esp_http_client_init(&config);
    esp_http_client_set_header(client, "Content-Type", "application/json");
    
    for(;;)
    {
        // wait for event trigger`
        xSempahoreTake( http_trigger_sem, portMAX_DELAY ) ;

        char post_data[15] = {0} ;
        sprintf( post_data, 
                 "{\"value\":\"%c\"}", 
                 LED_State ? '1' : '0' ) ;
        ESP_LOGI("Post Data:", "%s", post_data);
        
        esp_err_t err = esp_http_client_open(client, strlen(post_data));
        if( err == ESP_OK ) 
        {
            esp_http_client_write(client, post_data, strlen(post_data));
            ESP_LOGI(TAG, "%s", post_data);
            
            int content_length = esp_http_client_fetch_headers(client);
            if( content_length >= 0 ) 
            {
                int discard_count = 0 ;
                esp_http_client_flush_response( client, *discard_count ) ;
            }
        }
        
        esp_http_client_cleanup(client);
    }
}
```

By using a binary rather then a counting semaphore it will prevent an HTTP traffic storm that the web interface might not keep up and which would lag the actual LED state. The current `LED_state` is passed regardless of how many times it may have toggled while the previous HTTP exchange was in progress.

While you could use an interrupt for the button rather then polling, it is probably unnecessarily complex and you would have to deal with switch debounce to prevent multiple interrupts toggling the LED repeatedly.